# Call abstract class method from class name

Tags: php, abstract-class

I have a string containing the name of a class. This class is abstract, but has a public static method returning an instance of a child class.

```
abstract class MyClass {

   public static function instance() {
      return self::$inst;
   }

}
```

Now I need to call this method somehow and all I am given is the name of the class as a string. I can't say `$class = new $className()` because MyClass is abstract. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't create object for abstract class

Comment: I realize that. I don't need an object because as I said, I want to call a static method. I want to call MyClass::instance(), but I only have a string containing 'MyClass'

Comment: Abstract class is accessible via inheriting the class. You can't directly call to the abstract class methods http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have the classname in a string and want to call an abstract method of that class, you could do the following:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$instance = $className::instance();
```

Comment: That is probably because your 'MyClass' is abstract. You cannot instantiate an abstract class. If you want to create a class from a name in a string I suggest you do it with `$instance = new $className();` or with a factory like `$instance = ClassFactory($className);` for example.

Comment: ClassFactory is not defined in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for this - Reflection.

```
$refClass  = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
if ($refClass->hasMethod('instance') {
   $refMethod = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass', 'instance');
   $refMethod->invoke(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but if somebody is still looking, do the following:

```
$method = "myFunction";
$class =  "myClass";
$result = $class::$method();
```

So in the mentioned case use

```
$method = "instance";
$class = "myClass"
$instance = $class::$method();
```

But in your case the problem seems to be in your instance function. I guess you try to return an instance of your abstract class, which is not possible !